# Como cambiar la configuración del coma flotante en netbeans, de "," a ".". Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Actualmente Netbeans me lee los comas flotantes con el carácter "," y me lanza la excepción cuando inserto números con el ".". Me gustaría leer y escribir con el punto ("."). He cambiado en mi sistema la configuración de lectura de los decimales, pero  parece ser que eso no es suficiente. Alguna  luz¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Locale` te puede ayudar, acopla tu codigo al formato de la region seleccionada, te dejo un ejemplo:

Tu puedes pasar que tipo de formato local que quieres de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class PrintfLocales {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f: Default locale\n", 3.1415926535);
        System.out.printf(Locale.GERMANY, "%.2f: Germany locale\n", 3.1415926535);
        System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.2f: US locale\n", 3.1415926535);
    }

}
```

Esto te arrojaria algo como esto

```
3.14: Default locale
3,14: Germany locale
3.14: US locale
```

PD:

> Ejemplo recopilado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236056/force-point-as-decimal-separator-in-java